# Retrofit response codes with RxJava2

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2, android-networking

So I wanted to implement the example of response from the API like in this video
[droidcon NYC 2017 - Advanced Networking with RxJava + Retrofit](https://youtu.be/q4eK3VFhnA0?t=11m30s)

And this is my code:

**Presenter.java**

```
compositeDisposable.add(RetrofitClient.createService(GetApi.class)
            .getResponseFromServer(token)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<ResponseFromServer>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(ResponseFromServer responseFromServer) throws Exception {
                    mView.setResponseObject(responseFromServer);
                }
            }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                    if (throwable instanceof HttpException) {
                        int responseCode = ((HttpException) throwable).code();
                    }

                }
            }));
```

So here, when I get some 4xx error response from the server, I can go to `Throwable` and get the response code, and if response is okay I can get my object, and everything is cool.

However, in the video example above, the guy suggest that I wrap my `ResponseFromServer` with Response like this:
`Single<Response<ResponseFromServer>> getResponseFromServer(@Header("X-Authorize") String token);` so I can access response codes also, but in that case, my `Throwable` never gets called, so I can access to the codes only in the first accept method, but in the video he catch the errors in the `Throwable` section. So, I cant figure it out what I'm doing wrong? Maybe I'm using the wrong Observer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Response from Server is `code < 200 || code >= 300` in those cases `onError()` will be invoked. and other cases `onNext()` will invoke.

Also, If your code from `onNext()` throws any exception, that will be catch in `onError()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But unfortunately, when i have Observer in this form `Single<Response<ResponseFromServer>>` the 404 error is caught in the first accept, not in the onError, thats the main problem

Answer (score 5):

I think i figured it out, if we wrap our response object with `Observable<Response<Object>>` all of the response code will be caught in the regular accept method, so we kinda need to extract the codes manually and do the checks. However, if we keep the `Observable<Object>`, errorCode < 200 || errorCode > 400 will be caught in the onError method.

Comment: That is what I mentioned @RadoVidjen

Comment: @MilindMevada yes you mentioned the error code part which is important, but RadoVidjen's answer expands on that by telling us to wrap our response to be able to parse using Observable<Response<Object>> (however, I'm using Single<ResponseBody> which I think does the same thing in year 2020)